# Difference between tomcat in startup and service-based execution

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a very weird problem.
I have a j2ee application that uses safenet sentinel keys as a hardware lock.
And it's working fine every where else.

In a very special case on a virtual machine with win 2012 server and mounted hardware. The tomcat running as a service sees the key but when I tested with startup.bat I'm getting errors saying that the hardware does not exists

Both tomcats are the same and even I tried running startup.bat as administrator which makes no difference